# Using Array modifier to follow curve but without rotating

Tags: modeling, modifiers

a bit noob here and still learning. I am trying to make a waterslider spiral in Blender 2.92. And my initially thought was to make an array modifier follow a curve (spiral). I want some details on the top half of my cylinder, but when i am applying the array modifier, the object is also rotating, which means that the top half would eventually follow the curves rotating. Right now i am empty for ideas, i have tried adding an empty and playing with the object offset. Is there a way to lock the rotating axis or something, or some other ideas on how to make such an effect? . Thanks a lot[image: Image is showing the rotation of the object when adding adding the modifier, see that that top is also rotating]

Comment: maybe select the curve and try Object Data > Shape > Twist Method > Z-Up?

Comment: Have you tried screw modifier?

Comment: I have not tried the screw modifier yet, because then i would end up with one big object, and some tedious copy paste work when i want to add some detail to the object.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks alot @moonboots the solution with object data -> shape -> twist method -> Z-up was exactly what i needed!

[image: Z-up in object data -> shape -> Twist Method -> Z-up]

Answer (score 1):

You can manually tilt the curve. But...this is very tedious.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, i also have looked into that, but it was very tedious indeed, and very hard to get a uniform result